# Scaling a canvas. What am I doing wrong

Tags: javascript, canvas

```
$('#myCanvas').click(function (e) { //Default mouse Position 
        console.log(e.pageX);
$("#myCanvas2").attr("width", e.pageX );
$("#myCanvas3").attr("width", e.pageX );
        var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, e.pageX,400);
context2.putImageData(imageData,0,0);
context3.putImageData(imageData,0,0);
context.clearRect ( 0 , 0 , 2000 , 2000 );
$("#myCanvas3").css("scale", "(-1, 1)" );
$("#myCanvas3").css("transform", "scale(-1,1)");

 var canvas4 = document.getElementById('myCanvas4');
 var context4 = canvas4.getContext('2d');
 context4.drawImage( myCanvas2, 0,0 );
 context4.drawImage(myCanvas3, e.pageX,0 );


context3.scale(3,3);
    });
```

I am trying to scale my canvas with the scale command.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's going wrong exactly? Do you have a link to an example?

Comment: It just does not seem to scale. I have defined my context's just fine outside the function. The only thing that seems to not be working is the scale command.

Comment: This thread should help: [How to scale an imageData in HTML canvas?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448347/how-to-scale-an-imagedata-in-html-canvas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I'm not clear what you're trying to do, but these thoughts come to mind:**

To get an accurate canvas mouse position, calculate relative to the canvas element:

```
$('myCanvas').click(function(e){

    var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    var mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-BB.left);
    var mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-BB.top);
}
```

About mixing CSS and Canvas:

- CSS scale will operate on the center of the element.
- Canvas scale will operate from the origin (the origin defaults to 0,0).
- CSS scaling will not affect Canvas drawing.  So if you "flip" using CSS scaling and then you draw the flipped element to a canvas, the resulting canvas drawing is not flipped.
- Changing the canvas element width will also automatically clear the canvas content.
- Changing CSS width will retain the canvas content, but will "stretch" the existing pixels into the new width (the content will appear deformed).

Canvas scaling commands only affect drawings done **after** the scale command.  So your `context3.scale(3,3)` will not affect anything you have previously drawn on myCanvas3.

**Here's how to horizontally flip an image on a canvas element:**

Example code and a Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/tSPB2/

```
var img=document.getElementById("theImg");
var iw=img.width;
var ih=img.height;
var canvas2=document.getElementById('myCanvas2');
var context2=canvas2.getContext('2d');
canvas2.width=iw;
canvas2.height=ih;
context2.save();
context2.translate(iw,0);
context2.scale(-1,1);
context2.drawImage(img,0,0);
context2.restore();
```

[image]