# setAttribute of newImage()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am reading in an image through FileReader() and creating a new image object to put into a canvas. I successfully get the image into my canvas but I can not set the attributes of width and height to fit into my 600x800 canvas. The image retains its original size. How can I change the dimensions of the new Image object?

```
reader.onload = function(e) {
    var imgObj = new Image();
    imgObj.src = e.target.result;   //Successfully sets src
    imgObj.setAttribute("height", 200);
    imgObj.setAttribute("width", 400);
    ctx.drawImage(imgObj,0,0);  
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to scale an imageData in HTML canvas?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448347/how-to-scale-an-imagedata-in-html-canvas)

Comment: You're asking the wrong question. You want to draw an image to a canvas of given dimensions, and make the image fit. This can be done using the arguments of the `drawImage` method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage

Comment: _"but I can not set the attributes of width and height to fit into my 600x800 canvas"_ What is purpose of setting image `width` to `400` , `height` to `200` if `canvas` `width` is set to `600`, `height` set to `800` ?

Comment: @guest271314 just arbitrary numbers. Basically just means I want the picture inside the canvas smaller than the canvas itself.

Answer (score 1):

Here, you are setting the `width` and `height` of the image's HTML element which has no effect on the image data. To scale the image when drawing, you can pass the `width` and `height` during the [drawImage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) call.

```
ctx.drawImage(imgObj, 0, 0, 400, 200);
```

From the documentation, [drawImage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) accepts any of the following:

```
void ctx.drawImage(image, dx, dy);
void ctx.drawImage(image, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight);
void ctx.drawImage(image, sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight);
```

Here, all arguments prefixed with `s` reference the `source` image and all arguments prefixed with `d` reference where the image will be put, the `destination`.

Comment: This helps. Thanks. Also used the last suggestion in [How to scale an imageData in HTML canvas?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448347/how-to-scale-an-imagedata-in-html-canvas) as suggested by @zero298.

Comment: 9 arguments is ridiculous. whose can name the 7th one quickly without looking?

Comment: Once you get the hang of it, it's not hard. It's just image, source dimensions, destination dimensions. Making it even easier will be when the spread operator is widely implemented (already is in some browsers like Chrome). If you already have a 4-length array for source and destination, you can write `ctx.drawImage(image, ...src, ...dst)`. If you don't have those arrays you can also just group things together like `ctx.drawImage(image, ...[0, 0, 200, 400], ...[0, 0, 100, 500])`. Then it's easy for those people who find it hard to count to 9.